# Enviar cópia do formulário para a empresa e para o cliente

Tags: php, formulário, email

Olá!
Estou com um problema no envio de um formulário.
Ao submeter, os dados preenchidos são enviados para o meu email.
No entanto, eu gostaria que fosse enviada uma cópia para o email preenchido no formulário.
Já tentei alguns códigos mas não enviam para o email preenchido.
Este é parte do meu código:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$emaill = $_POST['email'];

$to = "mail@mail.pt";

$boundary = "XYZ-".md5(date("dmYis"))."-ZYX";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
$headers .= "boundary=" . $boundary . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "$boundary" . PHP_EOL;


if(mail($to, $assunto, $mens, $headers)){
```

Um dos códigos que tentei adicionar

```
$headers .= "Cc: $emaill" . PHP_EOL;
```

Mas não funcionou.

Alguém me consegue ajudar a perceber o que estou a fazer de errado?

Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Quando eu preciso fazer isso, coloco os e-mails separados por vírgulas, a função `mail();` aceita isso muito bem.

```
$to = "email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com";
```